# Error while exporting the column from MySQL in Laravel through routing

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5

I have Laravel project from [Github](https://github.com/AshutoshChoubey/SaiAutoCare), I am trying to export the selected column to a txt file. The table name is `customers` and the column name is `customer_contact_numbers` from the database `khanoilsdb`

Here is the error I am facing:
[image]
I have added a new controller and the following code to it:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CNController extends Controller
{
    $customers = Customer::all();
$phoneNumbers = "Phone numbers \n";
foreach ($customers as  $customer) {
  $content .= $customer->customer_contact_numbers;
  $content .= "\n";
}

// file name to download
$fileName = "contact_numbers.txt";

// make a response, with the content, a 200 response code and the headers
return Response::make($content, 200, [
  'Content-type' => 'text/plain', 
  'Content-Disposition' => sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', $fileName),
  'Content-Length' => sizeof($content)
];);
}
```

Web.php:

```
Route::get('/home', 'CNController');
```

And the button:

```
      <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('CNController') }}">Export</a>
  </div>
```

[image]

What I am trying to do is, after users click on it, it will call the controller method and start downloading a txt file.

Sorry if I'm not able to explain properly, I'm new to Laravel and PHP. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you don't have a function in your class.

You can add a new function `exportNumbers` like this:

```php
class CNController {
    public function exportNumbers() {
      // Your code here
    }
}
```

Then you have to edit the `web.php` file to call this function:

```php
Route::get('/home', 'CNController@exportNumbers');
```

Comment: Drik, thank you very much. I am getting this error:  `throw new InvalidArgumentException("Route [{$name}] not defined.");`
It said, `Route [CNController] not defined.` in `dashboard.blade.php`

Comment: `<a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ route('CNController') }}">Export</a>`